# Add div outside bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to use bootstrap twitter to format my site. When I add my several divs into the row-column format. I ve got a 9x9 grid with divs. I want to put one more element outside the grid in a fixed position. I use row-fluid and span class for my elments. How can i place my last element fully right of my page ??

My Code:

```
 <body onload='drawAll();'>
 <section>

    <div class="container-fluid">   
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="mapWidget" class="debug span8">
                <canvas id="map"  
                width="500" 
                height="280" 
                ></canvas>

                <canvas id="layer" 
                width="500" 
                height="280"
                style= "position:absolute;
                left:0px;
                top:0px;"></canvas>     
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="profiles" class = "span4">
                <script id="profileTemplate" type="text/template">
                    <div  class= "hashTags" id = 'redLine'>                 
                        <h1> <img src="images/tagIcon.png"/> HASHTAGS</h1>  
                        <br><font size = "6"><%= tagsCloud.tags[0] %> </font> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[1] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[2] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[3] %>  
                        <font size = "5"><%=tagsCloud.tags[4] %>  </font>
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[5] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[6] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[7] %></br> 
                        <br> <%= tagsCloud.tags[8] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[9] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[10] %> 
                        <font size = "6"><%= tagsCloud.tags[11] %> </font>
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[12] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[13] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[14] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[15] %></br>
                        <br><font size = "6"><%= tagsCloud.tags[0] %> </font> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[1] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[2] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[3] %>  
                        <font size = "5"><%=     tagsCloud.tags[4] %>  </font>
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[5] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[6] %> 
                        <%= tagsCloud.tags[7] %></br>   
                    </div>
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class = 'usersCloud debug span2'> 
                <h2 ><img src="images/chat.png"/>TOP COMMENTERS</h2>
                    <img src="images/userCloud.png" />
            </div>

            <div class = ' button span2'>
                <img src="images/menu.png"/>
            </div>


        </div>  

        <div class="row-fluid"> 
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">     
            <div id="footer" class="debug span4"><img       src="images/logo.png"/></div>   
        </div>
```

My very special element is the element with menu png image, when i put it outside the grid, it has unexpected behavior! Css code:

```
.button{
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
 display:inline-block;
 width: 24px;
 right:-80px;top:0px;
 position:fixed;
 }
```

Comment: I am a beginner in bootstrap,started today .can you give some good links to start as a beginner?

Comment: Check the following links: http://www.layoutit.com/build
http://www.williamghelfi.com/blog/2013/06/09/bootstrap-3-the-new-grid-system-for-starters/
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Comment: Is the above links from basic?Sorry for asking off the topic in your question

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is in your question...

Just add your div *outside the bootstrap framework* (so, not in a row or column) and then style it.

It won't take part in the responsive stuff that bootstrap applies but you can handle that by extending the bootstrap media queries with your own code...

Comment: Yes ok it sounds simple, but with the first change of the page size with the mouse, it begins the paranormal activity. Elements placed into other elements without any formatting.

Comment: OK - can't really do anything more without seeing some code . . .